# How can I download/save as a pdf presentation from a pdfviewer where the download button does not exist?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, download, save

I have a pdf file that has no save or download button. Is there a way to download this file. I tried to inspect the code but no much help there. I think there is no function within the file to download or save it. The viewer is a ordinary pdfviewer. I will appreciate it if someone has any idea how such a file could be saved for local use.

I attached a screenshot from the actual file. There is no other way.

[image: file sample]

Answer (score 0):

Press 'Alt-F' then 'A' on firefox. What your looking at is Firefox in a special mode for displaying and already downloaded pdf file. Thats a local copy your looking at, albeit stored in a temporary directory firefox uses. Pressing Alt-F then A will be "File>Save_As"